# Running node-rdkafka code in server

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, apache-kafka

I'm running the below node-rdkafka code in Eclipse as Node.js application. This is the sample code from https://blizzard.github.io/node-rdkafka/current/tutorial-producer_.html

I want to run this in a test server and call from iOS Mobile application.
I knew about running node.js app in AWS. 
**Question I**: Is there any other options to run in a free test server environment like Tomcat? 
**Question II**: Even If I am able to run this node.js app in a server, how do i call from a mobile application? Do I need to call *producer.on('ready', function(arg)*  (or) What function i need to call from Mobile app?

```
var Kafka = require('node-rdkafka');
//console.log(Kafka.features);
//console.log(Kafka.librdkafkaVersion);

var producer = new Kafka.Producer({
      'metadata.broker.list': 'localhost:9092',
      'dr_cb': true
    });

var topicName = 'MyTest';

//logging debug messages, if debug is enabled
producer.on('event.log', function(log) {
  console.log(log);
});

//logging all errors
producer.on('event.error', function(err) {
  console.error('Error from producer');
  console.error(err);
});

//counter to stop this sample after maxMessages are sent
var counter = 0;
var maxMessages = 10;

producer.on('delivery-report', function(err, report) {
  console.log('delivery-report: ' + JSON.stringify(report));
  counter++;
});

//Wait for the ready event before producing
producer.on('ready', function(arg) {
  console.log('producer ready.' + JSON.stringify(arg));

  for (var i = 0; i < maxMessages; i++) {
    var value = new Buffer('MyProducerTest - value-' +i);
    var key = "key-"+i;
    // if partition is set to -1, librdkafka will use the default partitioner
    var partition = -1;
    producer.produce(topicName, partition, value, key);
  }

  //need to keep polling for a while to ensure the delivery reports are received
  var pollLoop = setInterval(function() {
      producer.poll();
      if (counter === maxMessages) {
        clearInterval(pollLoop);
        producer.disconnect();
      }
    }, 1000);

});

/*
producer.on('disconnected', function(arg) {
  console.log('producer disconnected. ' + JSON.stringify(arg));
});*/

//starting the producer
producer.connect();
```

Comment: Your iOS app should be able to communicate with your server running on Eclipse

Comment: could you explain 'server running on eclipse' here? I am not running any server. you are asking me to run a tomcat in eclipse?

Comment: Sorry, I read you're running a Node server, not just a Kafka client. Anyway, you can run Tomcat (or a Node server) from Eclipse. You don't need to use AWS

Comment: Ok, Tomcat will be easy, I'll try now. Also, please share link/steps for running Node server. Also, Can you please answer to my 2nd question? which method i should be calling from mobile client as iOS http request?

Comment: IOS should have its own native Kafka client, so none of those Javascript ones

Comment: However, using Kafka from a mobile app might not be a good idea. Therefore, HTTP requests can be made to a REST proxy https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest

Comment: Hi, No. I have to run node-rdkafka in a server and call producer method through http request iOS client. If I can use native iOS kafka client or rest kafka APIs, then why should i be trying node-rdkafka now. This is not my requirement. My requirement is, to run node-rdkafka lib in a server and call producer method from http request iOS client via node-rdkafka.

Comment: Okay, then do it... You currently have no HTTP server, so start there. For example, use ExpressJS, not Tomcat

Comment: Ok. I'll install ExpressJS first now.

Comment: Is this the one. https://expressjs.com/ ? If yes, what is the next thing i have to do after executing $ npm install express --save

Comment: You write a web application. Follow some tutorials... Forget about the Kafka stuff until you can connect your iOS app to it

Comment: I got it. but if i know exactly how can that be connected with node-rdkafka Node.js app, then i am clear on what i'm going to do next.

Comment: You write an HTTP endpoint that just runs the `for (var i = 0; i < maxMessages` loop... You don't really need any of the `producer.on` blocks because the producer should ideally be ready/setup as the web server starts

Comment: I installed ExpressJS. I could able to run server.js (which has node-rdkafka code) file using command: $ node server.js

Comment: Okay, so is the problem solved? If so, you can answer your own question below with the solution. Otherwise, edit the question to explain the current issue

Comment: I didn't get what i've done now? Does it behave like a web server installed under this Node.js app? How can i call from a Mobile app? Thats my second question.Do I need to call producer.on('ready', function(arg) from a mobile app using http request?

Comment: Also, I can't write a web application which doesn't have 'producer' instance variable and call simply 'for loop' just like that. If you look at the code, 'for loop' should need 'producer' instance variable to call producer kafka API (producer.produce(topicName, partition, value, key);).

Comment: You can define the producer and use `producer.connect();` the same time you run `app.listen`... Your `app.get()` internals can run the for-loop with the defined `producer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need an HTTP server. ExpressJS can be used. Then, just tack on the Express code basically at the end, but move the producer loop into the request route.

So, start with what you had

```
var Kafka = require('node-rdkafka');
//console.log(Kafka.features);
//console.log(Kafka.librdkafkaVersion);

var producer = new Kafka.Producer({
  'metadata.broker.list': 'localhost:9092',
  'dr_cb': true
});

var topicName = 'MyTest';

//logging debug messages, if debug is enabled
producer.on('event.log', function(log) {
  console.log(log);
});

//logging all errors
producer.on('event.error', function(err) {
  console.error('Error from producer');
  console.error(err);
});

producer.on('delivery-report', function(err, report) {
  console.log('delivery-report: ' + JSON.stringify(report));
  counter++;
});

//Wait for the ready event before producing
producer.on('ready', function(arg) {
  console.log('producer ready.' + JSON.stringify(arg));
});

producer.on('disconnected', function(arg) {
  console.log('producer disconnected. ' + JSON.stringify(arg));
});

//starting the producer
producer.connect();
```

Then, you can add this in the same file.

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Ready to send messages!'))

app.post('/:maxMessages', function (req, res) {
    if (req.params.maxMessages) {
        var maxMessages = parseInt(req.params.maxMessages);
        for (var i = 0; i < maxMessages; i++) {
            var value = new Buffer('MyProducerTest - value-' +i);
            var key = "key-"+i;
            // if partition is set to -1, librdkafka will use the default partitioner
            var partition = -1;
            producer.produce(topicName, partition, value, key);
       } // end for  
    } // end if 
}); // end app.post()

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

I don't think the poll loop is necessary since you don't care about the `counter` anymore.

Now, connect your mobile app to `http://<your server IP>:3000/` and send test messages with a POST request to `http://<your server IP>:3000/10`, for example, and adjust to change the number of messages to send

Comment: I tried as you suggested, it is working. I need to test from Mobile App. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I might be late on this but this is how I did using promises and found it better than have a time out etc.

```
const postMessageToPublisher = (req, res) => {

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
producer.connect();
producer.setPollInterval(globalConfigs.producerPollingTime);

const actualBody = requestBody.data;

const requestBody = req.body;

const topicName = req.body.topicName;

const key = requestBody.key || uuid();

const partition = requestBody.partition || undefined;

const data = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(udpatedBody));

/**
 * Actual messages are sent here when the producer is ready
 */
producer.on(kafkaEvents.READY, () => {
  try {
    producer.produce(
      topic,
      partition,
      message,
      key // setting key user provided or UUID
    );
  } catch (error) {
    reject(error);
  }
});

// Register listener for debug information; only invoked if debug option set in driver_options
producer.on(kafkaEvents.LOG, log => {
  logger.info('Producer event log notification for debugging:', log);
});

// Register error listener
producer.on(kafkaEvents.ERROR, err => {
  logger.error('Error from producer:' + JSON.stringify(err));
  reject(err);
});

// Register delivery report listener

producer.on(kafkaEvents.PUBLISH_ACKNOWLEDGMENT, (err, ackMessage) => {
  if (err) {
    logger.error(
      'Delivery report: Failed sending message ' + ackMessage.value
    );
    logger.error('and the error is :', err);
    reject({ value: ackMessage.value, error: err });
  } else {
    resolve({
      teamName: globalConfigs.TeamNameService,
      topicName: ackMessage.topic,
      key: ackMessage.key.toString()
    });
  }
  });
});
};
```

Please note that kafkaEvents contains my constants for the events we listen to and it is just a reference such as kafkaEvents.LOG is same as `event.log`

and also the calling function is expecting this to a promise and accordingly we user `.then(data => 'send your response to user from here')` and `.catch(error => 'send error response to user`
this is how I achieved it using promises